Is there a way to share my deleted answer with others?
A friend asked me a doubt. I saw the question and realised that I had already answered it on this site. I went to my answers' list and couldn't find it anywhere. I realized it was deleted along with its parent question. The answer is quite long and long screenshots turn out to be of very poor quality on my phone.
Is there a way that I can share such an answer with someone who's not on this site?
Note: I'm not asking for restoration of the deleted question which is why I didn't even link it.
What can I possibly do? Ask that question myself and copy paste my previous answer then share it with my friend?  (The question wasn't a duplicate; it was deleted because it didn't show any research effort/ context.)

Access the question via a link (assuming you have such a link).  Click edit.  Copy and paste the text to your friend or whosoever you please.

@Shaun I wouldn't ask this if it was a text only question. It has MathJax code. How would it render?

That depends on their device, how they access it, etc., so I don't know.

@Shaun Nevermind, I just thought of a way! I'll post it on another site like Quora or something which supports MathJax.

Or you could post it in the Sandbox here then share a link to that revision of the answer.

Make a pdf using your favourite $\rm\LaTeX$ software.

Not optimal, since MathJax to Latex requires manual conversion.  This conversion must precede compiling the Latex into a pdf file.  Bill Dubuque's comment, which suggests using the Sandbox, avoids that, and merely assumes that the friend also has internet access.
